# Same font size looks different in same web browser

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have two JSP pages with the following code:

**A.jsp**

```
<fieldset>  
<legend class="noBold" >Datos generales</legend>    
<table> 
    <tr>
        <td class="etiqueta" colspan="5">
            <label for="fxPresentacion">Fecha presentaci&oacute;n:</label>
        </td>
     </tr>
     ... more code ...
 </table>
 </fieldset>
```

**B.jsp**

```
<fieldset>
<legend class="">Datos generales</legend>
<table class="estiloTabla"> 
    <tr>
        <td class="etiqueta">
            <label for="fxSolicitud">Fecha solicitud:</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    ... more code ...
</table>
```

Both pages uses the same CSS:

```
label {
    color: inherit;
    font-size: 0.98em;
    border: 0px;
}
```

And when you open it in a web browser, label tags looks with different font sizes:

**A.jsp**

[image: A.jsp]

**B.jsp**

[image: B.jsp]

Someone knows what's happen?

P.S: I have a web filter in my PC and I can't show the images. Here are the URL's:

A.jsp: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbxBQ.png

B.jsp: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbxBQ.png

Comment: Both lagend and table have different classes

Comment: Yes cor, but my problem is in <label> tag.

Comment: You're using `em` for your `font-size` which means it will scale in relation to the current font size. It would seem likely that a fixed width `font-size` is being set in a parent element somewhere.

Comment: I bet @HiddenHobbes is right. Check if you don't have a different font-size in the parent nodes of the problematic label.

Comment: Did you examine the element in devtools and see what actual size it is, and where that's coming from?

Comment: Rounding errors I imagine, 98% of most font sizes isn't going to give you an integer number of pixels.

Comment: Ahhh... ok!! Now I understand how it works :). I will check it!

Comment: The code posted does not reproduce the problem. The cause of the problem is in some part of CSS code that is not disclosed in the question.

Answer (score 2):

**ZOOM LEVEL** - Embarrassing, but my issue turned out to be that I had one browser window zoom level **set above 100%** whereas the other browser window had a zoom level of exactly 100%.  I don't know why I didn't think to check that first, but I'll post the answer here in case it helps someone else who didn't think of it.

Comment: You have saved me from going insane today!

I was being driven mad trying to understand why text inside CODE tags was one size (inline in text) and a different size when inside a PRE block.

What was worse, white-space: pre-wrap made it the same size - so it was just PRE-blocks where the text was smaller. Turned out it was exactly this issue.

I had the accessibility feature on the phone set to 130% text size, but it doesn't grow all tags - notably excludes PRE-blocks. (and DT, and a few others) leaving them much smaller. (too small)

So thank you for leaving this comment - lifesaver!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the browser's devtools for checking the "computed style".
There you can see...

- The calculated font-size
- The cascading rules which are respected

Without the complete page and the complete stylesheet it is only possible to guess.

Answer (score -1):

using root-ems `rem` instead of `em` could do the trick.

If you want to support older browsers you can use fallbacks. In this case it would look like this:

```
label{
    font-size:15px;
    font-size:1rem;
}
```

**They work like this:**
Older browsers will ignore the css rule they don't know (in this case rem). While newer browsers, which know the css rule, will simply overwrite the previous one.

Comment: Then i suggest a fixed size for IE8, and a relative size for never browsers. like this:
`label{font-size:15px;font-size:1rem;}`

Comment: +1 for @Schtailian's comment. This is exactly how I've supported font-sizes for IE8 in the past. It definitely works - just make sure px value comes first, rem second.

Comment: Thanks for the info Schtailian!! I will try it

Comment: Well, I use it and it fixes the problem. But after solve another issue, we find the true problem. Someone puts a table into another table...OMG! So, with em font-size, it looks smaller.

Comment: yep, thats not valid html. Better fix that stuff first :)